# Sql Query Optimization for counting and displaying (distinct value in column), grouped by other two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

From Column A, B and C, I am counting the distinct C where the table is grouped By A, B.
Below is the example table:

[image: img1]

and the output should look something like:

[image: img2]

I am running phpMyAdmin in my local computer using wamp server to test. My database has 500000 rows. I used following query and it took more than 180 seconds to run my query.

```
select A, B, count(distinct C)
from table
group by A, B
order by count(DISTINCT C) desc
```

Is there any optimal query that I can use for same result which will give me less runtime? Or, is it because I have large quantity of data in my table?

Comment: you just have to index your columns, they are used to speed up queries and will be used by the Database Search Engine to locate records very fast. See this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html

Comment: As you are new here do not put screenshots, put comma or pipe separated values in a table.Refer sqlfiddle.com

Comment: The query is straight-forward. Don't try to change it. In order to count, the whole table must be read and sorted. It may be that a covering index (`create index idx on table(a,b,c)`) could help. The DBMS might then read the whole index instead of the whole table and find the data prêt-à-porter. I don't know, however, how much work it is to traverse all branches of such an index. Maybe it is faster, maybe not.

Comment: After all, sorting should be a matter of a few seconds (you can try this with Excel on your computer), so does it take your computer so long to actually read the records from disk? Then you may want to defrag your table (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html) or your whole hard disk. (But well, it may still be that MySQL is just very slow on such operations, then there is little we can do about it.)

Answer (score 1):

For performance, you will need to add a [Composite Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) of `(A, B, C)` on your table.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name 
ADD INDEX(A,B,C);
```

Comment: Does MySQL actually use this index for t his query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I would expect it for two reasons:  1. It is optimal for the `GROUP BY`, and 2. it is "covering".  Still, an index scan of 500K rows may not be a lot faster than a table scan of the same number of rows.

Comment: @RickJames . . . I didn't phrase my question well.  Will this eliminate the sorting that `GROUP BY` normally does?  My guess is that the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` would confuse the optimizer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - If it can walk through the table (or index) in the `GROUP BY` order, no sort is necessary.  `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` may be attempted by some in-memory technique.  Run `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` -- there might be some evidence there.